# Cypress - Intercept Identical API Calls with different payload

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, uitest, cypress-intercept

I have two identical API requests but different payloads.
For example

1. Request URL: http://localhost:8000/getdata/

Request Method: POST

Request body:
{
dataCategory:"Hardware"
}

2. Request URL: http://localhost:8000/getdata/

Request Method: POST

Request body:
{
dataCategory:"Software"
}

My current code -

```
cy.intercept({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/getData',
   
}).as('apiCheck');

cy.get(desktopElements.SomeElement).click();
cy.wait('@apiCheck').then((interception) => {
    assert.isNotNull(interception.request.body.dataCategory, 'Request');
})
```

I know for a fact that I cannot include dataCategory inside the intercept method. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the intercept to be specific to the value of `dataCategory`, add a dynamic alias - ref documentation [Aliasing individual requests](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Aliasing-individual-requests)

```js
cy.intercept('POST', '/getData', (req) => {

  if (req.body.dataCategory === 'Hardware' ) {
    req.alias = 'hardware'
  }
  if (req.body.dataCategory === 'Software' ) {
    req.alias = 'software'
  }

  // or simply
  req.alias = req.body.dataCategory

});

cy.get(desktopElements.SomeElement).click()

cy.wait('@software').then((interception) => {
  assert(interception.request.body.dataCategory === 'Software', 'Request is Software');
})
```